# What does v, r, s in eth_getTransactionByHash mean?

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, signature, cryptography

In [Ethereum JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) I found the return is:

```
Returns

Object - A transaction object, or null when no transaction was found:
hash: DATA, 32 Bytes - hash of the transaction.
nonce: QUANTITY - the number of transactions made by the sender prior to this one.
blockHash: DATA, 32 Bytes - hash of the block where this transaction was in. null when its pending.
blockNumber: QUANTITY - block number where this transaction was in. null when its pending.
transactionIndex: QUANTITY - integer of the transactions index position in the block. null when its pending.
from: DATA, 20 Bytes - address of the sender.
to: DATA, 20 Bytes - address of the receiver. null when its a contract creation transaction.
value: QUANTITY - value transferred in Wei.
gasPrice: QUANTITY - gas price provided by the sender in Wei.
gas: QUANTITY - gas provided by the sender.
input: DATA - the data send along with the transaction.
```

But I type the command, the result is not same with the document above :

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"blockHash":"0x949f40920a86f281daccbe8e30dd60a366b22ff270647815f6bfc0402ff38e42","blockNumber":"0xce3","from":"0x047347096a6dc73f8626afb520c383a02efda314","gas":"0x15f90","gasPrice":"0x4a817c800","hash":"0x70a7552c8ab8d2621c80c8a1c149012d10a823c4619cc82235cbdfad0553310b","input":"0x021df6f4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d48656c6c6f2c20776f726c642100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d48656c6c6f2c20776f726c642100000000000000000000000000000000000000","nonce":"0x178","to":"0xe2412bb63a0a25d7b8973fc6764fd246ebe62c7a","transactionIndex":"0x0","value":"0x0","v":"0x1b","r":"0xd693b532a80fed6392b428604171fb32fdbf953728a3a7ecc7d4062b1652c042","s":"0x24e9c602ac800b983b035700a14b23f78a253ab762deab5dc27e3555a750b354"}}
```

What does `r`, `s`, `v` and others mean ?

And `value: QUANTITY - value transferred in Wei`, what does it mean?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`v`, `r`, `s` are the values for the transaction's signature.  They can be used as in [Get public key of any ethereum account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/get-public-key-of-any-ethereum-account)

A little more information, `r` and `s` are outputs of an ECDSA signature, and `v` is the recovery id. 
 https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38351/ecdsa-v-r-s-what-is-v also applies to Ethereum.  For replay attack prevention, Ethereum makes further adjustments to `v` as explained in [EIP 155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155).

---

`value` is how many Wei was sent to the `to` address.  1 ETH is 10^18 wei.

[QUANTITY](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#hex-value-encoding) basically means that the value is encoded in hex.

Comment: Why there are 27,28,189,190 values? trying to understand it. esp 189 and 190

Comment: @rstormsf Asking at https://crypto.stackexchange.com could be better.

Comment: I figured it out, it is result of applied chain_id number vs non-applied

Comment: Is it possible to have any abuse by having r, v, s? In terms of security.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. Not sure what you mean, r, v, s, are specific to a transaction (and nonce), so using r, v, s on another transaction will almost always have an invalid effect.  [Replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replay-attack) are a related area that you might be asking more about.

Comment: @eth Of course, I did not mean merely repeating the transaction, in general, any security issues. For example, forging a signature, signing a new transaction, security code, wallet identity information, or any other security issue.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. Maybe these answers will help? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/111260/why-is-it-not-possible-to-get-the-private-key-out-of-the-public-key or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54857/does-signing-message-weakens-the-address-security