# Does transaction have network id?

Tags: networkid

According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/how-to-select-a-network-id-or-is-there-a-list-of-network-ids), every Ethereum wallet has a number called `network id`.

Does every transaction have this `network id`?

If not, then it should be possible to replay transaction on multiple networks, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If not, then it should be possible to replay transaction on multiple networks, isn't it?

Replay protection was introduced in [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) by incorporating the chainID into the `v` part of a transaction's signature. So in effect, yes, the transaction does have knowledge of which network it is on.

From the [Specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md#specification) part of the EIP:

> If `block.number >= FORK_BLKNUM` and `v = CHAIN_ID * 2 + 35` or `v =
>   CHAIN_ID * 2 + 36`, then when computing the hash of a transaction for
>   purposes of signing or recovering, instead of hashing only the first
>   six elements (i.e. nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data), hash
>   nine elements, **with `v` replaced by `CHAIN_ID`**, `r = 0` and `s = 0`. The
>   currently existing signature scheme using `v = 27` and `v = 28` remains
>   valid and continues to operate under the same rules as it does now.

See also: [What does v, r, s in eth_getTransactionByHash mean?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/what-does-v-r-s-in-eth-gettransactionbyhash-mean)

And also: [What is a chainID in Ethereum, how is it different than NetworkID, and how is it used?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37533/what-is-a-chainid-in-ethereum-how-is-it-different-than-networkid-and-how-is-it/37571#37571)