# Find the public key of any ethereum account (that hasn't signed a transaction)?

Tags: web3js, addresses, public-key

I need to find the public key of a list of Ethereum addresses. Is it possible to do this only with the transaction hash of one of their transactions? Per [Get public key of any ethereum account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/get-public-key-of-any-ethereum-account) the v, r and s values of the signature when a transaction is sent is also required. Using `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` for example doesn't bring back this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a signature, there's no way to get the public key (short of someone giving it to you). So for an address that has never made a transaction, this can't be done.

(I'm not sure where `getTransactionReceipt` comes in. If you're calling that, then surely the account *has* made a transaction, so you *can* recover the public key.)

Comment: These would be for addresses that have made a transaction somewhere at some point (so I could find a transaction hash to look at for them) but I don't know how to get the v, r and s value for any transaction which seems to be required for finding the public key. Of course using `web3.eth.sign` returns v, r and s values but these accounts wouldn't be interacting with my website, I only have already-existing publicly viewable transactions to work with.

Comment: `eth_getTransactionByHash` will give you the `v`, `r`, and `s` values for a transaction.

Comment: (That's `web3.eth.getTransaction` if you're using web3.js.)

Comment: thanks - the docs at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction don't mention that as bringing back v, r and s values