# Public Key of existing wallet

Tags: go-ethereum

I have an ethereum wallet. How can I get the public key? I am getting the only private key.

Answer (score 1):

Public keys in ethereum does not hold much significance. Your account address is last 20 bytes of the hash of your public key and that is used for sending or receiving any transactions. But if you still need to get your public key, refer to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13892/29549) answer.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you are looking for your public address as you will probably not need public key for any activity, they are kept internally by ethereum to validate transactions, to get public address you can

1. go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info
2. select 'Private key' to access your wallet
3. Paste your private key and click 'Unlock Button'

MEW will show your public address with account balance and related info. you can also use browser extensions like metacast and desktop freewares to access your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ABDK Toolkit](https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/ethereum#key-to-address) to recover both, public key and address from your private key.