# Is it possible to derive public key from ETH address?

Tags: addresses, private-key, ipfs, encryption, public-key

Goal *(not asking XY question)*:

- send ETH to an address
- `web3.js` script monitoring it and acting upon transaction
- if `msg.value > 0.1 ether` then...
- ...encrypt a file with the public key of the `msg.sender` and publish to IPFS
- only the original ETH sender *(they have private key)* can decrypt the file

---

Looking at the question: [How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)

> 1. Start with the public key (128 characters / 64 bytes)
> 2. Take the Keccak-256 hash of the public key. You should now have a string that is 64 characters / 32 bytes. (note: SHA3-256 eventually became the standard, but Ethereum uses Keccak)
> 3. Take the last 40 characters / 20 bytes of this public key (Keccak-256). Or, in other words, drop the first 24 characters / 12 bytes. These 40 characters / 20 bytes are the address. When prefixed with 0x it becomes 42 characters long.

Public key to address is a one-way function, so how can we design the system to accomplish the goal?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a message (the transaction that send ether) and a signature (the signature of the transaction) you can recover the public key associated.

For example using this answer [Get public key of any ethereum account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/get-public-key-of-any-ethereum-account/13892), you can recover the public key given a message hash and the signature.