# How to encode message using public key ETH address?

Tags: security, ecdsa

I want to send an encrypted message to a specific ETH address via the blockchain.

> `Hello, my secret.`

Can I encrypt this message in the browser with the public key of the recipient's address? I understand that an ETH address is not a public key, but is it possible to somehow get it to a person who wants to send a message.

```
encode_public_key_ETH_address('Hello, my secret.') 
//=> 6ee825aafad19a0d759e1e0b
```

Send to blockchain.

So that only the recipient can decrypt it using the private key from the ETH address.

```
decode_private_key_ETH_address('6ee825aafad19a0d759e1e0b') 
//=> Hello, my secret.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to do. But you will need the public key of the person you are sending a message to.

As you correctly said, an address is not a public key. But you also can't, in general, "extract" a public key from an address (to do so, you'd need to have a signed transaction from the address as well, see [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/get-public-key-of-any-ethereum-account?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more on this).

The good thing is that nobody should be afraid of sharing their public key with you.

EDIT: This link should help you; it explains how to get a public key from a signed transaction: [Get public key of any ethereum account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/get-public-key-of-any-ethereum-account)

Comment: Thank you. It turns out to get the public key knowing only the address is impossible. You can find out when the user will make a transaction.