# How is the FROM address known for historic transactions?

Tags: transactions, rlp

The rlp encoded transaction that is stored in the ethereum database does not include the `from` address.  How is the `from` address known and how is it associated to the rlp transaction data when retrieving a historic transaction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoded transaction when [decoded](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/encoding/#utils.rlpDecode) has properties v, r and s.

```
{
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "maxFeePerGas": "0x1234",
  "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0x1234",
  "gas": "0x55555",
  "to": "0x07a565b7ed7d7a678680a4c162885bedbb695fe0",
  "value": "0x1234",
  "input": "0xabcd",
  "v": "0x26",
  "r": "0x223a7c9bcf5531c99be5ea7082183816eb20cfe0bbc322e97cc5c7f71ab8b20e",
  "s": "0x2aadee6b34b45bb15bc42d9c09de4a6754e7000908da72d48cc7704971491663",
  "hash": "0xeba2df809e7a612a0a0d444ccfa5c839624bdc00dd29e3340d46df3870f8a30e"
}
```

From this you can compute the public key of the sender, and then the address.

To compute the public Key check [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13892/53608) answer.