# Is it possible to retrieve an EOA public key from its Ethereum address by Solidity?

Tags: solidity, addresses, public-key

Is there a solution to retrieve or calculate the public key of an EOA account from its Ethereum address in Solidity? Is it possible?

Comment: Only the opposite !

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, but if you have a signed transaction from an address you can get the public key from the signature. See this [response](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13892/55861).

I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> calculate the public key of an EOA account from its Ethereum address in Solidity

It is not.

Answer (score 1):

Short: No, it is not possible.

Long: The public key is derived from the private key. The address is derived by hashing the public key and cutting the result to the last 20 bytes. Due to the characteristics of hashing functions it is impossible to calculate the input with a given output. Thus, it can be regarded as impossible to  get the public key of a given address.