# How to prove to someone that you're the owner of an Ethereum wallet remotely?

Tags: security, transfer, privacy, scam

Say someone you just met, Person A, claims that they had sent crypto to a scammer, Person B, and was defrauded by that scammer. Now Person A wants to get the money back, but has to prove that they are the victim who they say they are.

How can Person A prove to you that they were in fact the owner of the sending wallet that sent to the scammer, Person B, remotely if you are not physically nearby or are in different countries?

Answer (score 3):

So what you want to do is prove that a person is in possession of a private key which maps to certain address.

To do this you can ask him to sign some message with the private key (account). You can then use his public key to verify that it was indeed signed with the account's private key.

Since the account has already performed a transaction earlier, you can get the public key from the transaction like [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/get-public-key-of-any-ethereum-account).

Comment: Asking someone to sign a message involves coding ability right? Let's assume no coding ability

Comment: Probably some website offers such arbitrary functionality, but no idea which. Besides signatures one might consider some sort of zero knowledge stuff, but that's a lot more complicated. Do note that someone having certain address added in their wallet does not guarantee they have the address's private key - but that's a separate discussion.

Answer (score 1):

As i saw everywhere. For example you say "I will send 1 wei to 0 address". And then you execute a transaction with 1 wei sent to 0 address. I think this is a good proof.

Comment: Where did you "saw everywhere"? and what is "0 address"?

Comment: @user610620 "0 address" is default null address , usually used for burning tokens 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: why would someone send money to the burn address? what is 1 wei

Comment: It is just an example. You say you send an amount of money to a certain address and if that happen it means it is you. This was a way how community required to guys who says that they are Satoshi to prove that they really are Satoshi and everyone failed this test in this case. also KYC on your adress can prove that you own that address.

Comment: Please answer the questions in the last 2 comments.......

Answer (score 1):

you can confirm the identity by asking that user to sign a message and verify that signature.

This can be done with [Moralis Auth API](https://docs.moralis.io/authentication-api) like so:

- Request user to sign a message: https://docs.moralis.io/authentication-api/reference/request-challenge-evm
- Verify the signature: https://docs.moralis.io/authentication-api/reference/verify-challenge-evm

Disclosure: I work at Moralis

Comment: Can this also be used to verify identities of Bitcoin wallets?

Comment: Currently this is only compatible with EVM networks and solana