# How to get signed transaction hash - In order to retrieve an Ethereum address's public key

Tags: etherscan, cryptography, public-key

I'm trying to find a way to get the public key of an Ethereum's address. I found out that if an address has an outgoing transaction it's possible. I used Etherscan's "txlist" to get the address transactions, it would output something like this:

[image]

And then from the "hash" parameter I used Etherscan's "eth_getTransactionByHash" to get more information about the transaction and get v, r, and s. The output would be something like this:

[image]

Now having v, r, and s I was wondering if there's a way to retrieve the public key. I've found posts that using v, r, s and also "signed transaction" can compute the public key, but also couldn't find a way to get the "signed transaction" of an address from the list of its previous transaction. Thanks

Comment: here is the answer to your question. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/79174/19683

Comment: transaction hash is already signed, you don't get any new hash labeled as "signed". Transaction hash is just a hash on a bunch of fields of the transactions concatenated into a variable length byte array. Then this block is fed to Sign() function and it gives you the signature of the hash. That's what the process of signing a transaction do

Comment: you probably got mislead because in the libraries signed transaction is an object which has R/S/V fields set, and unsiged transaction has these fields set to "empty"

Comment: Thanks @Nulik, The thing that I suspect is that if I paste "hash" value in the ABDK toolkit it gives error and doesn't output the public key. what do you think?

Comment: @Nulik, I'm trying to follow this code https://scrapbox.io/piyopiyo/How_to_get_sender%E2%80%99s_Ethereum_address_and_public_key_from_signed_transaction
and it needs the signedTx, that's why I'm looking for it.

Comment: all transactions are signed so saying that you need a signed transaction doesn't make sense. If the transaction would be unsigned nobody would be able to verify it (because there are no R/S/V values present) , such transaction simply won't be accepted by any ethereum node.